# Calculate the spreading of points

Tags: euclidean-geometry, data-analysis, euclidean-domain

I have a set of points where a point is characterized by a pair of number $p_i = (x_i,y_i)$. The points are distributed in a specific area (say a rectangle). Is there a metric that characterizes the spreading of the points? Please have a look at the attached figures to see better what I'm trying to achieve. [image]
Points in the left figures have the spreading degree smaller than the right. I'm thinking about the sum of Euclidean distances, but it will depend on the number of points.

Comment: How about dividing by the number of points? $\frac 1 n \sum_{i,j} \|p_i-p_j\|$

Comment: Traditional is the average of the sum-squared distances of the points from the mean or average point.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Then probably I will combine the two suggestions. First calculate the average of sum-squared distances, then divide the number of points?

Comment: It is not a combination of the ideas.  It is precisely what I wrote (and which is used in ***Pattern classification*** (2nd ed.) by Duda, Hart, and Stork (Wiley).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork My mistake in understanding. Many thanks.

Comment: You can also calculate the measure David G. Stork describes by letting $$\sigma_x^2 = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2\\\sigma_y^2 = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 - \left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right)^2$$ and using $$\sigma = \sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2}$$ as your measure of spread. $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ are the standard deviations of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates. $\sigma$ combines them into a standard deviation of distance.